# How to call const function with type arguments?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, redux-form

Given this definition from the `redux-form` [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redux-form/lib/selectors.d.ts):

```
export type DataSelector<FormData = {}, State = {}> = (formName: string, getFormState?: GetFormState) => (state: State) => FormData;

export const getFormValues: DataSelector;
```

Note that `DataSelector` has two type arguments. If I am calling `getFormValues`, which is a `const` function, how do I supply the type arguments?

```
type FormFields = { name: string };


// No type argument specified so: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
const name = getFormValues('my-form')(state)?.name;


// I could cast it, but no thank you ...
const name = (getFormValues('my-form')(state) as any as FormFields)?.name;


// Need to supply `FormFields` as the generic argument for `FormData`, but how? This doesn't work ...
const name = getFormValues<FormFields>('my-form')(state)?.name;
```

1. Can I somehow specify generic arguments to the `const` function?
2. Are the typings wrong? How can they be corrected?

**Update:** The typings in this case are incorrect. Instead of...

```
export type DataSelector<FormData = {}, State = {}> = (formName: string, getFormState?: GetFormState) => (state: State) => FormData;
```

...it should be...

```
export type DataSelector = <FormData = {}, State = {}>(formName: string, getFormState?: GetFormState) => (state: State) => FormData;
```

...(generic arguments on the right side of the `=`) with this change, this is now valid:

```
const name = getFormValues<FormFields>('my-form')(state)?.name;
```

PR opened: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/49896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `getFormValues` is not a generic function, so there's no direct way to use it for your purposes. The type `DataSelector` is the same as `DataSelector<{}, {}>` because the definition of `DataSelector` uses [type parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).  So `getFormValues` essentially has the following typing:

```
declare const getFormValues: (
  formName: string, getFormState?: GetFormState
) => (state: {}) => {};
```

There's nothing generic in there anymore.  If you call `getFormValues()` it returns a function of type `(state: {}) => {}` which accepts (just about) anything and returns `{}`, an object type with no known properties.

---

I'm not really sure what the intended use of `DataSelector` is, nor how `getFormValues()` is implemented, so the following is just the typings I might use to get something that works for your particular example code.

If you want `getFormValues` *itself* to be a generic function, you'd need to move the generic type parameters off of the `DataSelector` *type* declaration and onto the *call signature*, like this:

```
type GenericDataSelector = <FormData = {}, State = {}>(
  formName: string, getFormState?: GetFormState
) => (state: State) => FormData;
```

and then have `getFormValues` be a value of *that* type:

```
const getFormValuesGeneric = getFormValues as GenericDataSelector;
```

This will give you the behavior you want, I think:

```
const nameOkay = getFormValuesGeneric<FormFields>('my-form')(state).name;
```

---

That works, although I'm a bit skeptical of generic functions without inference sites for the type parameters.  The `GenericDataSelector` type's call signature is generic in two parameters, neither of which appear in the parameters of the call signature... they only appear in the return type.

That means if I call `getFormValuesGeneric("something")`, the compiler has no idea how to infer what `State` and `FormData` should be, and it ends up defaulting to `{}` and `{}`.  If you want something different you need to manually specify it, like `getFormValuesGeneric<MyFormData, MyState>("something")`.

That works, but you end up in the weird position of saying that `getFormValuesGeneric<FormData1, State1>("something")` returns a function of type `(state: State1) => FormData1` while `getFormValuesGeneric<FormData2, State2>("something")` returns a function of type `(state: State2) => FormData2`. But of course at runtime the type system has been [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure), so both of those are just `getFormValuesGeneric("something")`.  How can two identical calls return two different function types that depend on stuff that's been erased?  They can't, really.

Meaning that *at most* one of `<FormData1, State1>` or `<FormData2, State2>` is the right choice for `getFormValuesGeneric("something")`... and choosing the correct one is, I guess, the responsibility of the person writing the TS code that calls the function.  But in that case there's not much of a difference between that and using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (what you called a "cast"); neither of them guarantee any kind of type safety.

Presumably there's some relationship between the value of the `formName` parameter passed in and the correct specifications for `FormData` and `State`, but this is not known to the compiler.  One could imagine rewriting the typings so that the compiler is able to keep track of this mapping, but I consider that well outside the scope of this question.

The takeaway from all of this is just **BE CAREFUL** when using generic functions whose parameters can't reasonably be inferred from anything.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDED2AnAtgZWAQ2NAvFAN5TYBcUAdgK5oBGEKUAvgNwBQ7okUAIrtgwQANhADGwVAB5k6fjiiEizADRQsuAsWYA+RVAAU7KFABmqNADlsaCBQDOwFAEtKAczVv4szDjwB+CjhECw08dgBKRT0DR00KMIgo-D0feWwOKC5waDhKRmcxdKFRCVR9GQt0-WU1RJrdIxNzdGtbBydXDygvEPREwNhvUL8ISOjDOLwE0eTUqoEOdgB6ZagAE3FhbBRoMSRKRx7h9AA1bGFqCHsKYpFxSRQlzbFt3ah9w+BjvrRzy+uFCaZgsbTsUEcLncnhOvk0g2CPkS4xSk1GFGUc20S240B8CGcInW9hqVBs4MhXRYS0+R16Pn+V3seQKYn09IsjOupBJLJcRQEJQeqGeWx2ewORym4OwlBANMl30o5IA8gBrbAgdmwrnMiD5fmVdAEon2HQGADkaBAAFoWmgLRFYrMAHTK2xLIA)

Comment: Thanks, exactly -- you can't specify type arguments for a const function -- it is constantly using the default type arguments of it's type. So the typings are wrong. To answer your question and to shed some light, the end user should be the one providing the typings to `getFormValues` if they wish to provide them. There is no tie from the form name to `FormData`.

Comment: I'm not sure "you can't specify type arguments for a const function" is the right way to say what's happening.  In my answer above, `getFormValuesGeneric` is a "`const` function", but it is generic and you can specify its type arguments.  Unless you mean "const function" in some other way.  I'd say "you can't specify type arguments for a non-generic function" instead.

Comment: Sorry -- yes, I see what you mean. Using your suggestion, I fixed the typings (as a test) by changing the declaration `export type DataSelector<FormData = {}, State = {}> = (...) => ...;` to `export type DataSelector = <FormData = {}, State = {}>(` (move the generic types to the right of the `=`. I'll fire off a PR for the typings -- thanks again!